# Getting Two 3/8” Inlets after Angle Valve

Tags: plumbing, faucet, shutoff

One of the PEX water outlets in my garage is currently connected to a 1/2 in. Nominal Compression Inlet x 3/8 in. O.D. Compression Outlet Multi-Turn Angle Valve (similar to one shown here).

[image]

I’d like to have two inlets from this shut off valve to a faucet and a laundry inlet. The first option I considered was to use a typical Dual Outlet valve. However the problem is when attempting to remove and replace the existing valve by the dual valve, the pipe itself somehow rotates as I wrench the valve to remove!

So I am now exploring any extension that can accept an 3/8” inlet and provides two 3/8”!outlets, which I can attach to the existing valve and be able to get two 3/8” one for faucet and one for laundry water inlet. Does anyone know any product that can do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate to this question: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/167258/inlet-valve-to-share-between-faucet-and-dishwasher

Comment: whay do you mean by the pipe rotates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a 3/8" compression tee fitting. This will require a short piece of 3/8" tubing between the valve and the tee. If you just go to a hardware store and ask there they might even have a tee with female on one side so it can screw right to the 3/8" outlet on your angle stop (the valve).

Answer (score 3):

`the pipe itself somehow rotates as I wrench the valve to remove!`

That will happen when you don't use **TWO wrenches** on pipe fittings.

**One** to remove the fitting, **the other to hold the mating fitting still.** Lucky for you it's just PEX, and PEX fittings will turn in the PEX (acting as a union does) - try that trick on a copper tube threaded fitting and you'll end up with a twisted and collapsed copper tube 99% of the time. Do it on an iron/brass pipe and you'll unthread an inaccessible fitting in the wall 50% of the time.